# Does Wiktionnaire tell me that à is required in "Viser à [faire qch]"?

Tags: dictionnaires

In a [question](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/30533/why-is-there-an-%C3%A0-with-visant-%C3%A0) I asked a few years ago, I learned that "viser à [infinitive]" is a fixed expression that means "to aim to do something". The WordReference [page](https://www.wordreference.com/fren/viser) for viser, at the time, did not have an entry for this expression, but now it does.

I then wondered if such an entry for "viser à [infinitive]" was omitted from WordReference because it should be obvious to us that "viser" could be used in an expression that meant "to aim to do something", and that *à* would be used in this expression. I (vaguely) remember being told elsewhere, though, that even if we knew that *viser* could be used in an expression with this meaning, that a good dictionary should tell us if *à* or *de* is used, because there is no rule that can reliably tell us whether *à* or *de* should be used.

So, when I look at the Wiktionnaire [page](https://fr.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/viser) for *viser*, I'm expecting to find information stating that "viser à [faire qqch]" is an expression. But, I can't seem to figure out where it says that information. Is there a different page I have to look on Wiktionnaire to find out this information?

Comment: It's under "Verbe 3". It's not really exceptional which would be why it's not shown as an expression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Viser à*** is described in the wiktionary page in the *Verbe 3* paragraph.

> *Avoir en vue une certaine fin, un certain résultat.*

According to the writers, the preposition ***à*** is not strictly required so ***viser à*** is not listed as a specific expression.

On the other hand, the [TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/viser) does list ***viser à*** as a set expression so it's a matter of opinion: whether ***viser*** in a sentence like *Deux risques majeurs sont visés par cette disposition* belongs to the *Verbe 3* entry or not.

I would tend to agree with the TLFi as in that sentence, the meaning is closer to this one from the *Verbe 1* entry:

> *Chercher à atteindre, à toucher.*

Comment: 1) so, if i undestand correctly, Wiktionnaire doesn't definitively tell me if which is correct, between: "viser [infinitive]" or "viser de [infinitive]" or "viser à [infinitive]"? (although, of course, maybe there are examples with "viser à", which might give me some clues)?

Comment: 2) (this is just a comment, not a question), but i'm getting increasingly uncomfortable with the fact that i cannot rely on a dictionary to tell me what prepositions are required after a verb, for a given meaning i intend when using the verb. maybe it is impossible for a dictionary to tell me this information, and that only thousands of hours of exposure will help me know? in this case (of needing to know what preposition (or lack of prepostiion) to use after a verb), writing my intended meaning using an English sentence, then using DeepL seems more reliable than trying to use a dictionary!

Comment: 3) does either the TLFi or Wiktionnaire help me know that "Le programme vise **à** réduire la pauvreté" is correct, but "Le programme vise **de** réduire la pauvreté" and "Le programme vise **[__]** réduire la pauvreté." are incorrect?

Comment: @silph L'expérience, monsieur, l'expérience... c'est ce qui vous donne la réponse correcte à chaque fois.

Comment: The TLFi is a frozen work made by "professionals", the Wiktionary is a work in progress collectively created by anyone who want to participate. Both approaches have their strengths and weaknesses. Dictionaries try to be exhaustive and give examples of what is been used but they usually do not give much examples of what is incorrect, as incorrectness has no limits...

Comment: Google NGram is also very effective in identifying [what is used or not]( https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=programme+vise+%2A+r%C3%A9duire%2C+programme+vise+r%C3%A9duire&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=30&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cprogramme%20vise%20%C3%A0%20r%C3%A9duire%3B%2Cc0)

Comment: @jlliagre maybe i can agree that a dictionary won't tell me what is incorrect, but was i wrong to have hoped that a dictionary could tell me that it should be "viser à"? or is there some grammar rule that lets me know that it's "viser à" instead of "viser de" or "viser [__]"? (i understand that DeepL and NGrams can help but i had hoped that a dictionary would help more definitively?)

Comment: @silph The TLFi states it's *viser à*: **B. − Empl. trans. indir., au fig. Viser à + subst. déterminé ou inf.**

Comment: @jlliagre right, of course. you even said so in your answer. sorry that my brain somehow malfunctioned.